# Прокручиваемый spinner

Tags: java, android

В диалоговом окне у меня имеется элемент spinner, но его содержимое не влезает в popupWindow, поэтому хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы элементы внутри этого spinner, то есть popupWindow, можно было свайпать (прокручивать). Как такое можно сделать? Заранее спасибо (:

Работаю со spinner из java кода (не суть, почему так, так надо), вот как это выглядит у меня

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
layout.addView(spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.days_spinner, R.id.textView, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.days));
                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: для начала приложите пожалуйста вашу реализацию данного элемента, и по возможности видео того что вы бы хотели исправить, так пока сложно помочь чем-то

Comment: @Andrew я не знаю, где сейчас можно найти такой тип представления, но могу примерно описать. Всё точно так же, как и в spinner, только окно, которое появляется при нажатии можно еще прокручивать, к примеру, как RecyclerView. Считайте, что я хочу вставить RecyclerView в spinner. Наверное, лучше будет сказать ScrollBar. Свою реализацию сейчас приложу

Comment: Попробуйте создать такой Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this, MODE_DIALOG);

Comment: @Style-7 Ни, мне нужен именно выпадающий список, а не диалоговое окно